# htaccess infinite redirect on password-protected subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, infinite

I have a website with two subdirectories, /1/ and /2/, appended to the end of the base url. Subsite /1/ already exists, and I'm trying to work on /2/ behind an htaccess password wall.

Going to the /1/ site works fine (and the root redirects all work as intended), but going to the /2/ site causes an infinite redirect when my htaccess password challenge is active. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
Redirect 301 /theforum http://www.leveluplabs.com/forum
RewriteEngine On

# stuff to let through (ignore)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/theforum/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/theforum" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/2/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/update/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/files/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/download.php"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
#

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.defendersquest.com/1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here's the .htaccess in the /2/ directory:

```
### Generated by Dreamhost. DO NOT modify!!! ###
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/defendersquest.com/2/.htpasswd
AuthName "Under construction!"
require valid-user
################################################
```

(/path/to/ is not the real path, I redacted the actual server path).

Any ideas? The page that generates the error is:
http://www.defendersquest.com/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your error.log as I suspect that either `/path/to/defendersquest.com/2/.htpasswd` doesn't exist OR doesn't have 644 permissions.

Request to `http://www.defendersquest.com/2/` is redirecting to `http://www.defendersquest.com/1/failed_auth.html` which in turn doesn't exist either and causing it to go to `http://www.defendersquest.com/1/missing.html` and looping.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't have any error logs - the "logs" directory is empty. I'm certain the path exists, so perhaps it's the permissions issue. How would I set the permissions?

I can reach the /2/ site just fine so long as it's not password protected, in case that extra detail helps. (Please forgive me being a total noob about all this).

Comment: Ok then make sure you're using proper encrypted password file and for permission you need to run `chmod 644` from shell.

Comment: what am I chmod'ing? the htaccess/htpasswd files or the /2/ directory itself?

Comment: .htpasswd file and .htaccess file

Comment: Okay, just did

chmod 644 .htpasswd
chmod 644 .htaccess

Still get the error. Anything else I can do to narrow this down or clarify things? Like letting failed_auth.html through so it doesn't infinite redirect?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line to the begining of the htaccess code.

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

That fixes the error when error handling system is confused where to send the user in a certain circumstance and goes into a loop. Sometimes it has been seen to be ending up with 404 not found.

This worked for me in a custom coded website and for a wordpress installation as well.